# How to move pdf from iBooks to another app like Photos on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, pdf, books

there was this pdf file i wanted to originally take off Safari into my iPad, and the only way to do that seemed to be saving it in iBooks.
But after that, is there a way to export the pdf from iBooks to the Photos app directly or indirectly? Any work around appreciated

Comment: It does not seem to be possible on iOS to open PDF's on Photos.app. There are other apps that will open it though; on my iPhone Evernote and  Google Play Books will. What would you like to do with the PDF that iBooks won't let you? Or is it something on Photos.app that you would like to replicate with PDF's?

Comment: Thanks I want to draw a signature on it... But to import into a drawing app it can be done onlly from Photos, and not ibooks. Evernote is almost perfect but it does not let you draw without becoming an annotation.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add this information? Also, the title should state this intention as the answer to the original appears to be that is not possible, but what you want to do is actually possible. This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my iPhone. I just opened the pdf in iBooks and took a screenshot (holding down the circular button and the on/off button of my iPhone at the same time). Then the screenshot of the pdf appears in your Photos roll, and you can zoom in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Photos does not appear to be able to open PDF files. But if what you want is to open the PDF in an app that allows you to edit it, there are many.

I've tried Skitch (editing costs extra), but there are plenty.

This [list](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/642-3-best-pdf-reader-apps.html) alone has 10 apps that can open PDF's on iOS :

- [Adobe Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/app/adobe-acrobat-reader/id469337564?l=en&mt=8)
- [Foxit Mobile PDF](https://itunes.apple.com/app/foxit-pdf/id507040546?mt=8)
- [PDF Reader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-reader-lite/id368377690?mt=8&at=1l3v52U&ct=TomsGuide)
- [iAnnotate](https://itunes.apple.com/app/iannotate-pdf/id363998953?mt=8)
- [Kindle](http://itunes.apple.com/app/kindle/id302584613?mt=8&at=1l3v52U&ct=TomsGuide)
- [Google Play Books](http://itunes.apple.com/app/google-play-books/id400989007?mt=8&at=1l3v52U&ct=TomsGuide)
- [Mantano Reader Premium](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mantano-ebook-reader/id768229929?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4)
- [PDF Expert](http://itunes.apple.com/app/pdf-expert-fill-forms-annotate/id393316844?mt=8&at=1l3v52U&ct=TomsGuide)
- [PDFpen 2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pdfpen-2-highlight-markup/id924203665?mt=8&at=1l3v52U&ct=TomsGuide)
- [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8&at=1l3v52U&ct=TomsGuide)

I haven't tried all of them, some are free, some paid, and some have editing capabilities, if you provide more information on what exactly is your situation, the software recommendation could be better.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to address OP's concern directly. App recommendations could be helpful, but maybe the answer can be edited to outline steps which can be taken to export a PDF document from iBooks. You can also mention that Photos app doesn't support reading PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

You can email the pdf to yourself. Then access the document from your email. This is how I work around the problem.